# While downloading something at the same time on label it should write downloading c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, download, label

Hi ppl im trying to make it write downloading while im downloading a file with C# i tried thread method but it still writing after the download finishes codes are below;

```
  public void yap(object o)
    {

      (o as Label).Text ="DOWNLOADING";

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        ParameterizedThreadStart p = new ParameterizedThreadStart(yap);
        Thread t = new Thread(p);
        t.Start(label2);
        string yol = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        FtpWebRequest FTP;
        try
        {

            FileStream SR = new FileStream(yol + "\\list.gz", FileMode.Create);

            FTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create
  (new  Uri("ftp://"+textBox1.Text+"/" + "/usr/valapp/etc/list.gz"));

            FTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            FTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            FTP.UseBinary = true;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)FTP.GetResponse();

            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            long cl = response.ContentLength;

            int bufferSize = 2048;
            int readCount;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (readCount > 0)
            {
                SR.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            ftpStream.Close();
            SR.Close();
            response.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR");
        }
    }

}
}
```

As i told codes are working but i just want to write download at the same time or first thank you.

Comment: Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is a really bad idea. It doesn't make your code safe - it just stops you from finding out that your code is broken. It's irrelevant as it happens, as you're currently doing everything on the UI thread, which is why the UI is freezing.

Comment: Thanks.So what you suggest me to do ?

Comment: Either use an asynchronous API, or perform the download in a background thread, e.g. using `BackgroundWorker`. I was wrong in my previous comment though - you're not doing everything in the UI thread. The one thing you're doing in a different thread is... updating the UI. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows app, I think the best would be to use `BackgroundWorker` and `Dispatcher.Invoke()` for updating label's text.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Update label text here..

      BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
      _backgroundWorker.DoWork += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;
      _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(delegate()
        {
            //Download code here..
        }));
}
```

Comment: thanks but i don't know javascript can you give me the codes that i need ?

Comment: Yes this is a windows form app

Comment: is it web app or windows app??

Comment: I tried it and i get these errors; 1- The name Dispatcher does not exist in the current context 2-The type of namespace 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'. What I'm missing :/

Comment: try to add reference to the `WindowsBase` dll

Comment: I tried WindowsBase before you said it solved Threading problem but Dispatcher still has the red line :/

Comment: I already added using.System.Windows.Threading but i cant add or use System.Windows.Dispatcher

Comment: I solved the problem      Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(delegate() is solving thanks everyone